# How to add multiple parameters to a GET request in a django template?

Tags: javascript, html, django, request

I have a page with a table of objects. Users can choose a filter from a dropdown menu:

```
<a href='?filter1=black'>Black</a>
<a href='?filter1=white'>White</a>
```

Which adds the filter into the GET request, like so: website.com/products?filter1=black

Now I want users to be able to combine that with another filter:

```
<a href='?filter2=black'>Small</a>
<a href='?filter2=white'>Big</a>
```

So that the GET request will look like this: website.com/products?filter1=black&filter2=small

How does one usually go about this (preferably in django template language)?

Comment: How would you "reset" the filtering, given you are "appending" extra items to the queryset.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot click on two buttons at the same time to get two values on the URL.  As soon as you click on one, the GET request will be sent.

So, you'll have to use a <form> with two <input> fields (or <select> in your case since you have known values the user can select from) and a single submit button that will submit the form once the two values have been selected.

MDN has great tutorials on this (and many other topics):  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms  (no sense in me trying to repeat that in my answer).

Comment: Not at the same time. When the first filter is already applied, and the user chooses from the second, I want it to be appended to the current url (which contains the first filter).